# Show that $F_g$ is $C^1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Given:

- $g: U ⊆ E → ℝ$, of class $C^{k+1}$ (where $k ≥ 0$ is a non-negative integer);
- $E$ a real normed space;
- $U$ open in $E$.
- $T = {α ∈ C^k([0, 1], E) : α[0, 1] ⊆ U}$.

Show that, for $k=0$:

$F_g : α ∈ T → g ◦ α ∈ C([0, 1], ℝ)$ is $C^1$.

---

Book exercise on Introduction to Manifolds. Just not clicking for me.

I do know that composition of $C^k$ functions is itself $C^k$, it isn't related to that, is it? As for $k=0$ we would have a $g$ $C^1$ and α $C^0$... Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from first principles, but the statement is wrong: If $\alpha \in C^0,$ then $F_g$ may not be in $C^1$ (make $E=\mathbb{R},$ then set $g(x) = x$ and $\alpha$ is a $C^0$ function which is not $C^1.$ If the $C^k$ is meant to be $C^{k+1}$ then the proof follows by using the standard $\epsilon, \delta$ argument with the definition of derivative.

Comment: My mistake, just edited. α ∈ T.

Comment: @ssvnormandysr2 I don't see anything different.